# Modify multiple files in different folders with one command?

Tags: shell, files

I have a file `abc.txt` in the folder `/etc/zyz/` and also in a few sub folders `/etc/zyz-1/` `/etc/zyz-2/`

How can I modify all of those files with a `echo` command for example (all named `abc.txt`) in every folder that starts with `/etc/zyz`? In some machines there are only two folders, in other there are 10+

Example of commands I want to run

```
echo 'New line data' >> abc.txt

abc.txt < /dev/null
```

Comment: With what `echo` command? What do you want to do to the files?

Comment: I have added the two commands I want to use above.

Comment: The second command doesn't do anything. Well, it will give an error but nothing apart from that. What do you want it to do?

Comment: It should empty abc.txt

Comment: Um, no. That would be `> abc.txt`. In any case, why would you go to the trouble of writing something to a file only to immediately delete it?

Comment: The command is in the wrong order sorry. I will empty it first and then write the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following tree (empty abc.txt):

```
.
├── zyz
│   └── abc.txt
├── zyz-1
│   └── abc.txt
└── zyz-2
    └── abc.txt
```

You can list all the abc files with:

```
$ echo zyz*/abc.txt
  zyz-1/abc.txt zyz-2/abc.txt zyz/abc.txt
```

And you can use `tee -a` to append some input stream to all of those files at the same time:

```
$ echo 'New line data' | tee -a zyz*/abc.txt
  New line data
```

If you do it twice, each abc.txt will contain two lines:

```
$ cat zyz/abc.txt
  New line data
  New line data
$ cat zyz-1/abc.txt
  New line data
  New line data
$ # ...
```

To empty them, you can do:

```
$ </dev/null tee zyz*/abc.txt
```

or

```
$ : | tee zyz*/abc.txt
```

(You shouldn't hit the ARG_MAX limit with only a few files with short names, but with a large number of files I'd use `find -exec` in the `+` form (see the manpage).)

Comment: That was a typo. It should have been `|` rather than `>`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two common approaches for this: `find` and shell globbing.

1. `find` has an `-exec` option which lets you specify an action to be performed on each of its results. It makes each of find's results available as `{}` and you can modify them as you wish. It's slightly more complicated when you want to give arguments (such as `echo foo > file`). For that, you need to tell find's `exec` to run a shell. So, to echo `foo` into each of the files found, you would run:

   ```
   find /etc/ -name abc.txt -path "/etc/zyz*" \
       -exec bash -c "echo 'New line data' >> {}" \;
   ```
2. Shell globbing. Certain shells (bash, zsh and ksh off the top of my head, but I'm sure there are more) can deal with recursive globbing. In bash, this is activated by `shopt globstar`. So, to echo `New line data` into each of the files, you would run:

   ```
   shopt globstar
   for f in /etc/zyz*/**/abc.txt; do echo "New line data" >> "$f"; done
   ```